# How to "update" Magento 2.0.2 to v 2.0.3

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.0.2, magento-2.0.3

I just got an announcement to upgrade Magento to 2.0.3

Is there a way to go from 2.0.2 to 2.0.3 through the Admin UI Panel without destroying all the work I have done so far in my setup?

Answer (score 2):

1. Log into admin
2. Go to **System** -> **Web Setup Wizard**
3. Enter your Authentication keys in "**System Configuration**". Create keys from [here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customerdata/secureKeys/list/)
4. Click on "**System Upgrade**" to start upgradation wizard.

Note: You have to make sure that Magento crons have been setup. See [How to setup Magento 2 crons](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron)

Comment: Thank you @Arvind07. I'll give it a try shortly and post back.

Comment: This does not work. You should see my 2 related Q's http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114275/how-long-to-wait-for-a-magento-2-x-upgrade and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114292/how-to-tell-if-system-upgrade-is-still-running-via-web-interface @Arvind07