# How to get Started Creating a Configurable Product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I am trying to follow the Magento 2 documentation on creating a configurable product.

The very first step in the doc fails.

screen shot 1 (Magento Doc makes it look easy)

[image]

screen shot 2 (my Magento does not work)

[image]

**Amendment #1**

I have built 14 attribute sets so far

[image]

**Amendment #2**

If it helps anyone troubleshoot the issue, here are the user instructions I have created for my client as pre-requisites to setting-up products. These are the 2 steps to setup an Attribute and an Attribute Set. Thank you for any comments or help in how to create Configurable Products in Magento 2.0.2

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I've answered your question below; however I am editing your question to remove the comment "Why is Magento so buggy?" as it is not constructive.

Answer (score 0):

**May 2016:**

This is due to a bug that has yet to be patched. Create a simple product, save, change to a configurable.

More info: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2567

---

This is because in your new install you have not created any attribute sets yet. This is not a clickable link or a field with dropdown options if you only have one single attribute set.

To create new attribute sets from the admin panel click on `Stores > Attribute Sets` and click "Add Attribute Set" button.

Comment: I already built 14 attribute sets @philwinkle -- see my amended screen shot

Comment: Also @philwinkle, you can look over the steps I created for my client to setup an Attribute and an Attribute Set. Maybe there is a flaw in the process somewhere. Your expert assistance is so greatly appreciated.

Comment: @H.Ferrence for posterity my answer is technically correct; it seems there is a bug since January with a known workaround. See here. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2567 and updating answer

Comment: Well that just stinks. My site is so hosed. I cannot upgrade it as I am stuck with v2.0.2 (http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/how-to-update-magento-2-0-2-to-v-2-0-3 | http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114275/how-long-to-wait-for-a-magento-2-x-upgrade | http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114292/how-to-tell-if-system-upgrade-is-still-running-via-web-interface)